# Previous Activity Not Being Updated After Launching Another Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I am having an issue where an Activity is not processing data after a new Activity is launched.

1. A singleton object X is created to be globally used.
2. Activity A is launched.
3. Activity B is launched.
4. In the mean time, object X sends background data to Activity A to update Activity A. However, it appears that nothing is going on in the background.

Does anyone have any clue? Do I need to override the onStop() function to allow Activity A to be updated?

Answer (score 1):

Uset `startActivityForResult` and override `onActivityResult` in `Activity` A. I think theres no way (and no use) for updating an inactive `Activity`.